# Exec Format Error using Codelite IDE and Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, mingw, codelite

I am trying to run a C++ program using the IDE Codelite on an Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS computer with MinGW compiler (i686-w64-mingw32). When I execute it gives the error "Exec Format Error". I can't figure out how to fix this. I appreciate any advice.

Comment: The advice you need now is how to write a Stackoverflow question with the best chances of getting a helpful answer. To do that, you should take the [tour], read the [help], and learn [ask] questions, and specifically the requirements for a [mre]. Your question contains little information that would be useful to anyone who would want to answer it.

Comment: The problem is not with the code, as I can't even run the generic "Hello world" program that comes with every new project in Codelite, therefore code is not included in my question. What other information would you want?

Comment: Which commands and options, for example, get executed. When using a graphical IDE all of this low level information is general not very accessible. In exchange for pretty buttons and colorful menus, when something goes wrong it means you often have no clue what's misconfigured and what needs to be fixed. Perhaps, until you gain more experience, it will be easier for you to learn C++ the old-fashioned way: open a plain text editor; write C++ code; learn how to run the compiler from the command line; learn how to create a `Makefile`; type `make` at a shell prompt; see what ***really*** happens.

Answer (score 2):

You say you are trying to run a program, correct? MinGW is a cross-platform toolchain *for Windows*. Nothing you build with it will run natively on Linux. Use [GCC](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/) if you want to write an application you can run.
When you say "execute", do you mean build using Codelite or execute the program? A Codelite error could be a bug, or a misconfigured setting, or something. A simple google of "exec format error" told me the error came from an app failing to execute. It is typically followed by a description, such as "permission denied". It is most likely, however, to be because you are trying to execute a windows application.

Comment: I am using Codelite's build and run option which opens terminal to execute. The program compiles without errors in Codelite, then the error appears in terminal. I tried selecting GCC as the compiler within the settings and it is giving the same error. Do I need to uninstall/reinstall Codelite because I set it up with MinGW initially?

Comment: Did you rebuild the program with GCC? Your project might have retained the settings.